# Show Error if Duplicate found in ensureIndex MongoDB Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**I have successfully stopped duplicate entries in MongoDB Database, But my issue is whenever a duplicate entry called, it was not returning any error and just stopping the node server**

How to throw any custom error like **res.send('duplicate entry')**..

i am using **forever start server.js** for non stop server.

Here below the code for my issue..

```
  router.route('/new_order')

  .post(function(req, res, next){

  var order_no = req.body.order_no;
  var origin_port = req.body.origin_port;
  var destination_port = req.body.destination_port;
  var expected_date = req.body.expected_date;
  var status = 0;
var item = {
  order_no: order_no,
  origin_port: origin_port,
  destination_port: destination_port,
  expected_date: expected_date,
  status: status
};
  var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/transport_main';
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    db.collection('orders').ensureIndex( { order_no: 1 }, {unique:true}, function(err){
      db.collection('orders').insertOne(item, function(err, result){
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log('New Order Insterted');
         db.close();
         res.send('true');
       });
    });
  });
```

});

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `assert` in production code, handle errors properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved This issue**

11000 is the Duplicate error code which calls while trying to insert. Not while ensureIndex.

ensureIndex was just checking the index created or not, if not it will re-create for us.

important : remove "assert.equal(null, err)" while attempting to insert.

```
mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    db.collection('orders').ensureIndex( { order_no: 1 }, {unique:true}, function(err, result){
        db.collection('orders').insertOne(item, function(err, result){
          console.log(err);
          if (err) {
            if (err.code == 11000) {
              res.end('Duplicate Entry Found');
            }
          }
          console.log('New Order Insterted');
           db.close();
           res.send('true');
         });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
db.collection('orders').ensureIndex( { order_no: 1 }, {unique:true}, function(err){
if(err) return res.send("You are already registered");...
```